# Can data be sent to Google Analytics from Meteor.js server side?

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I've built an app using Meteor.js. Now I'm extending that app to become an API and reply using only JSON data. When my app only lives server side, how can I implement Google Analytics into it?

Code snippet:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('methodExample', {
        path: '/api',
        where: 'server',
        action: function() {
            // standard GA code snippet
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-9', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The error I get is:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

If I replace `document` and `window` with `this.url` I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'l' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The server does not have direct access to the Client's DOM, which is what it looks like you are trying to do.  At least not that I know of.  The code that you are posting above seems to be the generic client-side code, which I believe does some DOM manipulation to cause the analytics data to be sent to Google when the page loads.

You could, however, do calls to remote HTTP web services from within the server code.  The [http](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http) package comes to mind here, but I am sure there are others on [Atmostphere](https://atmospherejs.com) as well.  It would allow you to make a call to the web service, which I am sure you can find examples on how to do in order to send Google Analytics data directly from JS without requiring a page load.  I did a quick web search and found Google has an [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) that seemingly does just that.  And, doing a search on [Atmosphere for "analytics"](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http?q=analytics) found at least a few packages that already include the analytics.js JavaScript library into your Meteor app.